# How to download Android SDK components offline?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am using latest version of (android-studio-bundle-135.1740770-windows 7)

I have completed the installation process, but when I open the Android SDK it says "downloading components". I let it download, but the download fails with this error:

```
  ****// Refresh Sources:
  Failed to fetch URL 

  (http://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml), reason: Unknown Host dl.google.com
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Failed to fetch URL 
  http://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl.google.com
  There is nothing to install or update.
  The following SDK component was not installed: 
  build-tools-21.1.1 ***///
```

I found a solution from Google for downloading these components offline using a direct link to the repository, but the repository contains lots of files. Which files do I want to download?

Answer (score 0):

Adding SDK Packages:

By default, the Android SDK does not include everything you need to start developing. The SDK separates tools, platforms, and other components into packages you can download as needed using the Android SDK Manager. So before you can start, there are a few packages you should add to your Android SDK.

To start adding packages, launch the Android SDK Manager in one of the following ways:

```
In Android Studio, click SDK Manager in the toolbar.
If you're not using Android Studio:
    Windows: Double-click the SDK Manager.exe file at the root of the Android SDK directory.
    Mac/Linux: Open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory in the location where the Android SDK was installed, then execute android sdk.
```

When you open the SDK Manager for the first time, several packages are selected by default. Leave these selected, but be sure you have everything you need to get started by following these steps:

1. Get the latest SDK tools

   As a minimum when setting up the Android SDK, you should download the latest tools and Android platform:
       Open the Tools directory and select:
           Android SDK Tools
           Android SDK Platform-tools
           Android SDK Build-tools (highest version)
       Open the first Android X.X folder (the latest version) and select:
           SDK Platform
           A system image for the emulator, such as
           ARM EABI v7a System Image
2. Get the support library for additional APIs

   The support library is required for:
       Android Wear
       Android TV
       Google Cast

   It also provides these popular APIs:
       Navigation drawer
       Swipe views
       Backward-compatible action bar

   The Android Support Library provides an extended set of APIs that are compatible with most versions of Android.
3. Open the Extras directory and select:
       Android Support Repository
       Android Support Library
4. Get Google Play services for even more APIs

   The Google Play services APIs provide a variety of features and services for your Android apps, such as:
       User authentication
       Google Maps
       Google Cast
       Games achievements and leaderboards
       And much more
5. To develop with Google APIs, you need the Google Play services package:

   Open the Extras directory and select:
       Google Repository
       Google Play services

   Note: Google Play services APIs are not available on all Android-powered devices, but are available on all devices with Google Play Store. To use these APIs in the Android emulator, you must also install the the Google APIs system image from the latest Android X.X directory in the SDK Manager.
6. Install the packages

   Once you've selected all the desired packages, continue to install:
       Click Install X packages.
       In the next window, double-click each package name on the left to accept the license agreement for each.
       Click Install.

   The download progress is shown at the bottom of the SDK Manager window. Do not exit the SDK Manager or it will cancel the download.
7. Build something!

   With the above packages now in your Android SDK, you're ready to build apps for Android. As new tools and other APIs become available, simply launch the SDK Manager to download the new packages for your SDK.

   While this is the step outlined in the Andriod developer site, it outlines the basic tools needed to get started...

HOPE IT HELPS!